# Runtime computation of my implementation of LCS

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime, big-o, lcs

Please help me in trying to find the runtime of my implementation of largest common substring problem

```
int main(){
    string a;
    string b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    string::iterator a1,b1;
    string max,temp;

    for(a1=a.begin();a1!=a.end();a1++){

        b1=find(b.begin(),b.end(),*a1);
        if(b1!=b.end()){
            temp+=(*b1);
            while( ((b1+1) != (b.end())) and ((*(a1+1))==(*(b1+1)))){

                a1++;
                b1++;
                temp+=(*b1);
            }
            if(max.size()<temp.size()){
                max.assign(temp);

            }
            temp.clear();
        }

    }
    cout<<max;
}
```

the function std::find takes O(n) time right. So this should be O(nm) where n and m are lengths of the strings. IS it more than O(nm) ?

Comment: `std::sort` takes time O(n log n) (as do most standard implementations of sorting algorithms). Also, remember that you can't discount the time required in the `find` step, which will take time O(m). Based on that, what do you think the runtime is?

Comment: You have to use dynamic programming to solve it in `O(n.m)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 how is this worse?

Comment: @templatetypedef i never used sort. I meant find, so n calls to find which takes O(m) time thats O(nm) right?

Comment: with `a = "abbbbbba" and b = "ababbbbbba"`, your result is wrong.

Comment: Is O(nm) greater than O(nm)? No, they are equal :-). Correct the text, please. What is more that O(nm)?

Comment: Please don't use `and`, `or`, `not` and the like in C++, use the operators. They are greatly frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

Worst Case of Your Implementation is the case where the two strings are identical. In this case Time Complexity is O(n*m) ,n-> outer loop ,m ->find or extending the match
BTW you dont have to use temp string ,just use counter of the length